# I'd like to cross-compile a gcj program for windows in linux

Tags: java, gcj, libgcj

I already have my program compiling on the linux gcj, but i'd like to statically compile for windows.

I've failed for linux. It always says:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcj
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Has anyone succeed at this (a portable java gcj binary statically liked for windows).
I don't want pointers to ExcelsiorJet or launch4j (that doesn't statically or AOT compile anything).

Comment: Why in God's name are you using gcj? A cursory search (here or on google) will turn up many points telling you that gcj is incomplete, slow, buggy, and just plain never worth using.

Comment: Because it's the only free option to statically compile java that doesn't increase the download size by 80mb (uncompressed). Why am i statically compiling a java app? Well, i want to distribute it with a C program that would call it. And i use wine. Imagine me (that deletes wine many times over a week) installing the JRE 30 times. I say no to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the Windows GCJ from http://www.thisiscool.com/gcc_mingw.htm
Follow the (GCJ 4.2) options on http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Statically_linking_libgcj to statically link libgcj.

Yes, it works on Wine.